# Object must be locked to be used?

Tags: thread-safety, language-features, mutex

I was pondering language features and I was wondering if the following feature had been implemented in any languages.

A way of declaring that an object may only be accessed within a Mutex. SO for example in java you would only be able to access an object if it was in a synchrnoised block and in C# a Lock.

A compiler error would ensue if the object was used outside of a Mutex block.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I think some people have misunderstood the question, I'm not asking if you can lock objects, I'm asking if there is a mechanism to state at declaration of an object that it may only be accessed from within a lock/synchronised statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that.

Your program either refuses to **run** a method unless the protecting mutex is locked by the calling thread (that's a `runtime check`); or it refuses to **compile** (that's a `compile time check`).

First way is what `C# lock` does.

Second method requires a compiler able to evaluate every execution path possible. It's hardly feasible.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can add the `synchronized` keyword to a method, but that is only syntactic sugar to wrapping the entire method body in a `synchronized(this)`-block (for non-static methods).

So for Java there is no language construct that enforces that behavior. You can try to `.wait()` on this with a zero timeout to ensure that the calling code has acquired the monitor, but that's just checking after-the-fact

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you can use the `@property` and `@synthesize` directives to let the compiler generate the code for accessors. By default they are protected by mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Demanding locks on everything as you describe would create the potential for deadlocks, as one might be forced to take a lock sooner than one would otherwise.

That said, there are approaches similar to what you describe - [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), in particular, avoids the deadlock issue by allowing rollbacks and retries.